# Sum the series $(1^2+1)1! + (2^2+1)2! + (3^2+1)3! \cdots + (n^2+1)n!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

**Problem:**

Sum the series: $$(1^2+1)1! + (2^2+1)2! + (3^2+1)3! \cdots + (n^2+1)n!$$

**Source:** A book on algebra.I came across this *interesting* looking series and decided to tackle it.

**My try :**

All I have tried is taking the $r^{th}$ term and summing it, but in vain:
$$ T_r = (r^2+1)r!$$
$$T_r = r^2\cdot r! + r!$$
Now I don't know how to sum either of these terms.I'm not familiar with uni level math as I'm a high school student. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Hint. Note that
$$(n^2+1)n!=n(n+1)!-(n-1)(n)!$$
Therefore the sum can be written as
$$(1(2)!-(0)(1)!)+(2(3)!-(1)(2)!)+(3(4)!-(2)(3)!)+\dots +(n(n+1)!-(n-1)(n)!).$$

Comment: how do I go forward now?

Comment: Should I plug in integers?

Comment: See my next line.

Comment: Simple rearrangement, duh! Thank you Robert Z :)

Comment: How do I think like that? I mean this way to solve doesn't come easily does it @RobertZ ?

Comment: The right term is "telescopic sum" See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: @YourAverageEuler A good way to come up with these sorts of answers is to try the first few terms and attempt to "guess" the answer. If you have what you think is a reasonable "guess", you can try to backtrack into the formula of each terms as a difference by subtraction.

Comment: @YourAverageEuler For "simple" situations one can make a guess. However there is a general strategy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair

Answer (score 2):

$$
S=\sum_{r=1}^n\left( (r+2)!-3(r+1)!+2r!\right)\\
=(n+2)!+(n+1)!-3(n+1)!-3\cdot2+2\cdot1+2\cdot2\\
=n(n+1)!
$$

Answer (score 2):

I will prove by induction that
$$\sum _{k=1}^n \left(k^2+1\right) k!=n (n+1)!\quad(*)$$
Indeed it is true for $n=1$ because $(1+1)1!=1(2!)$

Now suppose $(*)$ is true and let's prove it for $n+1$

$$\sum _{k=1}^{n+1} \left(k^2+1\right) k!=\sum _{k=1}^n \left(k^2+1\right) k!+\left[(n+1)^2+1\right](n+1)!=\\=n (n+1)!+\left[(n+1)^2+1\right](n+1)!=(n+1)!(n+n^2+2n+1+1)=\\=(n+1)!(n^2+3n+2)=(n+1)!(n+2)(n+1)=(n+1)(n+2)!$$

Hope this is useful

Comment: Yes, it is useful thanks @Raffaele